# (ActionScript 3) Children and clearing the screen issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash

I've been learning ActionScript 3 recently, and for the past 2 hours I have been stuck on this:

I cannot clear the screen when using the usual

```
while (numChildren)
{
  removeChild(0)
}
```

I have managed to create this app that allows me to control a green dot with the WAS keys (I haven't done the D key yet >_>), however it leaves a trail, despite my best efforts to clear the screen. I come from a Java/C# background, so if I'm doing something wrong, any advice would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

/**
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public var Player:EntityPlayer = new EntityPlayer();
    public var EntityDrawList:Array = new Array();
    public var EntityList:Array = new Array();
    public function Main():void 
    {
        addChild(Player.EntityGraphics);
        EntityDrawList.push(Player.EntityGraphics);
        EntityList.push(Player);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDownEvent);
        UpdateScreen();
    }

    public function KeyDownEvent(Key:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (Key.keyCode == 87)
        {
            Player.YLoc -= Player.EntitySpeed;
            UpdateScreen();
        } else if (Key.keyCode == 65) {
            Player.XLoc += Player.EntitySpeed;
            UpdateScreen();
        } else if (Key.keyCode == 83) {
            Player.YLoc += Player.EntitySpeed;
            UpdateScreen();
        }
    }

    public function UpdateScreen():void
    {

        while (numChildren > 0)
        {
            removeChildAt(0);
        }

        for (var e:int = 0; e < EntityList.length; e++)
        {
            addChild(EntityDrawList[e]);
            EntityList[e].drawEntity();
        }
    }

}

}
```

I have created 2 arrays; One which will hold the base class, and another that will hold the drawing variable (Yes, shapes.). The classes shown here can be seen (I will only show the Entity one, as the Player class only contains a variable called Lives and extends the Entity class:

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
/**
 * ...
 */
public class Entity extends Sprite
{

    public var XLoc:int = 0;
    public var YLoc:int = 0;

    public var EntityWidth:int = 20;
    public var EntityHeight:int = 20;
    public var EntitySize:int = 20;

    public var EntitySpeed:int = 1;

    public var EntityGraphics:Shape = new Shape();

    public var EntityTeam:int = 0;
    /**
     * Teams
     * 0: Player
     * 1: Ally
     * 2: Enemy
     * 3: Neutral
     * 4: Prop
     * 5: Tameable
     */

    public function Entity() 
    {

    }

    public function drawEntity():void
    {
        if (EntityTeam == 0)
        {
            EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0x15FF00, 1);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.drawCircle(XLoc, YLoc, EntitySize);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.endFill();
        } else if (EntityTeam == 1) {
            //EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0x, 1);
            //EntityGraphics.graphics.drawCircle(XLoc, YLoc, EntitySize);
        } else if (EntityTeam == 2) {
            EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.drawRect(XLoc, YLoc, EntityWidth, EntityHeight);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }

    public function eraseEntity():void
    {
        if (EntityTeam == 0)
        {
            EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFF, 1);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.drawCircle(XLoc, YLoc, EntitySize);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.endFill();
        } else if (EntityTeam == 1) {
            //EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0x, 1);
            //EntityGraphics.graphics.drawCircle(XLoc, YLoc, EntitySize);
        } else if (EntityTeam == 2) {
            EntityGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.drawRect(XLoc, YLoc, EntityWidth, EntityHeight);
            EntityGraphics.graphics.endFill();
        }

        drawEntity();
    }

    public function RemoveEntity():void
    {

    }

}

}
```

If there is an easier way to clear the screen, Google has not been friendly with sharing that. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You should use container clips and keep references to everything.  You're using arrays so you get that part?  So removing a player would look like mcPlayersHolder.removeChild(aPlayers[i]);  That references the clip using the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the removeChildren() function of the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @MasterRoro , but could you be a little more specific on where I should put this code, or how to use it?

Comment: Absolutely. Instead of your `while(numChildren > 0){}` loop. Just use removeChildren() which should do the same thing.

Comment: The answer provides a good alternative, still the right answer is that removeChild(0) should generate errors since it's a pure and simple code mistake. removeChilsAt(0) is what the PO should use.